# How to change python way of casting float('inf') to str?

Tags: python, casting, infinity

My app is processing numbers, and of them are pythons `float('inf')`.
The problem is that I'd like for such number to be casted as full word: `"Infinity"`.

```
for x in [float('inf'), float(5.0)]:
    print(x)
```

Results with:

```
inf
5.0
```

I would like it to be:

```
Infinity
5.0
```

Can I somehow set how infinity is represented in string?

Of course I could make something like method below:

```
def cast_num(num):
    if num == float('inf')
        return 'Infinity'
    else:
        return str(num)
```

But such method is costly - It has to process every number.

Is there better alternative?

Is there some flag in python which I can set? (like 'setlocale')

Comment: How would you imagine to do this *without* processing every number?

Comment: What data structure are your numbers stored in? List, numpy array, postgres table, etc? There may be opportunity for some small performance improvements, but you haven't provided a [mcve]

Comment: @wim e.g. "atoi" function, setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, '') changes the way how numbers are cased. Without setlocale atoi("123,123.34") is rising exception, but with this set its not. So I assumed, may there be some INFINITY_STRING variable that I could set :)

Comment: Are you using a pandas dataframe, ndarray, set, or other data structure?

Comment: @DavidFelipeMedinaMayorga - simple list. Updated question with example.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot monkey patch `float` string formatting because it is hard-coded in C. Therefore, you have to roll your own formatting code one way or another.

Comment: @ravenwing  Ah, I see.  Nope nothing like that, short of compiling your own Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use a simple dictionary :

```
values = {float('inf'):'Infinity'}
i = float('inf')
p = 0.5
print(values.get(i, str(i)))
print(values.get(p, str(p)))
```

## Output

```
Infinity
0.5
```

Comment: Note that `float('nan')` in a dictionary does not work reliably - see e.g. `float("nan") in {float("nan"): "Not valid"}` returns false.  After fixing the syntax error, is that really the output you get, because I would expect `nan` instead of `Not valid` in the output?  And this still checks every value anyway, I don't think it's really any better than what the O.P. already had - perhaps it's even worse, because of the nan issue.

Comment: @wim I checked this one, and it is the fastest as for now (probably some optimization magic for looking up for key in dict).

As for 'nan' -> I didn't check this one, because my original question was just about infinity.

Comment: So you showed Output but that's not actually the real output, is my point. And you still have a syntax error in the code.

Comment: Fixed the syntax error - that is what edits are for :-). as for nan - that is surprising until I realised that nan is never equal to anything - even itself.
Apologies for that. Have edited to remove that option. I tested the infinity option, didn't think to test the NaN option.

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`, this might be a good solution for you:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([2.0, float('inf'), 5.0], dtype='<U8')

x[x=='inf'] = 'Infinity'
x
```